# How to return either a vector or string based on condition in ifelse statement?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to write a function that creates a scatterplot - of which the points may need to be colored based on a variable or not.

I tried the following approach. But it doesn't color the points by group. Although the code runs fine without the ifelse statement.

```
data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100,sd=2),
           y1 = x*0.5+rnorm(100,sd=1),
           y2 = fitted(lm(y~x))) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -x,
               names_to = "Group",
               values_to = "yy")

group <- "Group"
ygroups <- 2
defaultcol = "black"


ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x , y = yy,
                                  color = ifelse(ygroups > 1, get(group), defaultcol))) +
  geom_point()

# runs fine
ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = x , y = yy, color = get(group))) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `ifelse` in this case because you need to return vectors of different length that your input. Just use a regular `if/else`

```
ggplot(data = data) + 
  aes(x = x , y = yy, color = if(ygroups > 1) get(group) else defaultcol) +
  geom_point() + 
  labs(color="Color")
```

But you can't set selecific default colors in an `aes(color=)` -- that will remap the color name via your color scale. If you just want to conditionally add the scale, then do

```
ggplot(data = data) + 
  aes(x = x , y = yy) + 
  {if( ygroups > 1) aes(color=.data[[group]])} +
  geom_point()
```

(using `.data[[ ]]` is recommended over using `get()`)